# Went thru puddle now says im out of gas?

Tags: fuel-system, dodge, ram

I have 13 Ram 1500. I recently replaced fuel pump and sensor and battery. Last night i filled up my tank . i wound up going through a huge puddle as we had flooding. Next thing i knew my gas light came on and my gage says empty. It then went to 1/4 tank. This morning it still says empty. No gas smell or anything. I checked dont see leak. Any idea?

Comment: Check the tank level sender connections either they have been dislodged or they need to be dried out.

Comment: Are you actually out of gas (engine stalled) or does the truck continue to run?

Comment: I'd say it'd be what @SolarMike said; Check the connections. Unplug them and blow any residual water out with compressed air or just blow as hard as you can if you don't have a can of compressed air or a compressor. Allow it to dry out during the day if it's dry and see if the problem still remains after it's dried. If it was that, you could try putting some dielectric grease inside where the wires are crimped to create a connection.

Comment: Also to further, did the tank get damaged at all or did the fuel level detection float get damaged/bent? This may be the cause, though I don't see why it would happen. If the fuel tank looks like it's taken a beating, it could be bent to the point that the fuel is funneling away from the side the fuel float is at, though this seems unlikely if you merely went though a puddle.

Maybe the fuel tank has been dislodged ever so slightly, either tilted forwards or back? Maybe the body ground connections are drenched from the water or loose? Check all of these, and I hope one of these fixes it! GL!

Comment: Ok so last night started truck it was back at full tank as it warmed up it went to half. Should i leave it a little longer and let it dry or is it better to drive it? My concern is i do roadside assistance so i don't want to break down on a way to a call lol. Also there was white smoke it was 20° so im thinking that was just the cold??

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have new fuel tank and sensor . everything looked ok so im thinking that was just water.

Comment: @Paulster no it runs . i had literally just put $60 and filled it not 20 more before. I immediately checked for a fuel leak but there is none.